# How to change hidden atribute on .htaccess file on OSX Server when access via SMB from Windows?

Tags: mac-osx-server

How can I remove the hidden attribute on a .htaccess file that is stored on an OSX server that is accessed from a Windows machine via SMB? When I currently remove the hidden attribute it does not stick.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think adding

```
hide dot files = no
```

to either the `[global]` section of /etc/smb.conf (which'll make it apply to all share points), or the specific share point's section of /var/db/samba/smb.shares.  Note that these files may get overwritten (either due to a settings change or system update), so be prepared to reinsert that directive as needed.